# User input not displaying when called via button. Using arraylists Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, arraylist

Currently working on a Java Swing application to store the name, type and weighting of a College student's assessment. They can add multiple Assessments (to store in an ArrayList) using a GUI button and display the input using the Display button on the GUI. I have searched for an answer to my problem, I am a beginner in Java and am using instantiable classes with GUIs, and don't understand the related questions that use the scanner, apologies if I'm wrong.

I have no error in my code, however when I press my display button the Name, Type and Weighting fields are blank.

This is a picture of my GUI:

[image]

This is my Assessment class where I declare my variables/getters and setters:

```
package arraylistexample;

public class Assessment {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private double weighting;
    private int count;

    public Assessment(){
        name = new String();
        type = new String();
        count = 0;
        weighting = 0.0;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double getWeighting() {
        return weighting;
    }

    public void setWeighting(double weighting) {
        this.weighting = weighting;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}
```

This is the relevant source code for my GUI featuring my ArrayList and the add/display buttons. I haven't coded the other buttons yet:

```
package arraylistexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class AssessmentGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private ArrayList<Assessment> aList;
private String name, type;
private double weighting;
private int count;

/**
 * Creates new form AssessmentGUI
 */
public AssessmentGUI() {
    initComponents();
    aList = new ArrayList<>();
    name = new String();
    type = new String();
    weighting = 0.0;
    count = 0;

}


private void addBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //get Textfield text

    name = nameTf.getText();
    type = typeTf.getText();
    weighting = Double.parseDouble(weightingTf.getText());

    Assessment a = new Assessment();
    a.getName();
    a.getType();
    a.getWeighting();

    //add to arraylist
    aList.add(a);

    //increment counter
    count++;
}                                      



private void displayBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    for(int i = 0; i < aList.size();i++) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+aList.get(i).getName()+"\n Type: "+aList.get(i).getType()+"\n Weighting: "+aList.get(i).getWeighting());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use set methods

delete :

```
a.getName();
a.getType();
a.getWeighting();
```

add :

```
a.setName(nameTf.getText());
a.setType(TypeTf.getText());
a.setWeighting(Double.parseDouble(weightingTf.getText()));
```

Also JOptionPane in loop is not good solution to show results

Answer (score 2):

You're not putting any data into your Assessment object after creating it.

```
// you get data but do nothing with it here
name = nameTf.getText();
type = typeTf.getText();
weighting = Double.parseDouble(weightingTf.getText());

// you create an Assessment object
Assessment a = new Assessment();

// you call a bunch of getters??? Shouldn't you be calling setters?
a.getName();
a.getType();
a.getWeighting();

aList.add(a);
```

Solution: call your Assessment setter methods, not the getter methods, when you want to set the state of the Assessment instance.

```
a.setName(name);
a.setType(type);
a.setWeighting(weighting);
```